# Shell commands in AsciiDoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I frequently use blocks of code in my asciidoc. The biggest issue I have is that shell commands beginning with '#' (because they use a root's shell) are rendered as comments in the asciidoc. For example:

```
[source,shell]
----    
# firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone dockerc
----
```

This make the reading a bit confusing. Is there a way to use a shell piece of code, overriding the 'behaviour' ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to set a [source-highlighter](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#enabling-source-highlighting)
For me the following example worked for HTML:

```
= Foo
:source-highlighter: coderay

[source,shell]
----
# firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone dockerc
--------
```

Or can you post a screenshot of how your output looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `[source,console]`, which is intended to represent text that’s typed into a console (i.e., a terminal application) instead of `[source,shell]`, which is used for the contents of a shell script.

Source: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/verbatim/source-highlighter/#shell-vs-console

For example, this produces correct highlighting for console input:

```
[source,console]
----
$ sudo -i
# add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
# apt update; apt install git
$ exit
----
```

[See output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVvyo.png)

Whereas the following renders lines that are prefixed with a `#` as light grey comments:

```
[source,shell]
----
$ sudo -i
# add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
# apt update; apt install git
$ exit
----
```

[See output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1spN.png)

The source-highlighter attribute has to be set in the document header, of course. By the way, regarding this, Asciidoctor PDF documentation states:

> Rouge is the preferred syntax highlighter. The use of CodeRay is no longer recommended.

Source: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/syntax-highlighting/